# pyinstaller raspberry pi compiling, how to execute program from command line

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller, executable

This executable generation is on raspbian linux, on my raspberry-pi:

Install pyinstaller: (I had to try this several times, as I got the error "http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response" but it suddenly worked):

$ pip3 install pyinstaller

In directory with my tiny_test.py file:

$ pyinstaller -F tiny_test.py

Then, in the created dist folder, I tried to run the compiled executable:
$ tiny_test

This gave the error:

"tiny_test: tiny_test: cannot execute binary file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## short answer:

$ ./tiny_test

## long anser:

Check the executable file properties:

$ file tiny_test

"tiny_test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=ad32521ad141d04ca4fc066798301621367c7964, stripped"

LSB executable files need to be run like this:

$ ./tiny_test

This worked for me!